# Python Code to Find out Mean and Trends on a Dataset

Tags: python

I have a dataset with four columns, Date, Subject, Student, Marks_Obtained. I want to find the mean Marks_Obtained I am trying to understand how can I implement a Python code where I need to find the mean Marks_Obtained across all subjects by each student.
I also want to implement how to find out the trends of the students who are improving over time, basically to find the student improving the most vs students who is improving the least over time with respect to the marks obtained.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTVDB.png)

Comment: please share input,output,implemented code and whatever you tried so far? 
 @StoneCold

Comment: @Roshan added the dataset

Comment: Use Pandas library. Let's not re-invent the wheel. :)

Comment: What is the data format? csv? I suggest you learn how to load your data to python first. `pandas` is a useful package for dealing with formatted datasets. You can start by reading the documentation first.

Comment: @AjayShah can you share some examples? I am new to this.

Comment: @KevinFang this is a CSV. I was able to load the dataset.

Comment: check few examples here: http://pythonforengineers.com/introduction-to-pandas/

Comment: I suggest you see this before diging into 'pandas' it is not good to reinvent the wheel,but it is good to know how it works if you plan to stay in that area: [data science](http://www.saedsayad.com/data_mining_map.htm)

Comment: Oh I see!! there was something missing in my question. So basically, I get it how to calculate the averages across all the subjects. Not sure how do I calcuate average of all the subjects for each of the student?